# Translating an AJAX put request into a Python request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, json

I have the following AJAX PUT request that was given to me. I'd like to run it from a Python script. I'm new to everything AJAX/HTTP related, so I'm guessing. Here's the request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: <insert base URL here> + "/state",
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            state: "<insert state here>",
            state_modified_by: $.cookie("<insert username here>")
        }),
        complete: function(data) {
            document.location.reload();
        }
    })
```

Here's my attempt at implementing the same request in Python using the requests library:

```
import requests

url = <insert base URL here> + "/state"
data = json.dumps({"state" : "<insert state here>", "state_modified_by" : "<insert username here>"})
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}

response = requests.put(url, headers = headers, data = data)
```

That gets me a "bad request" response from the URL.

Things I'm definitely unsure about:
 - Is using the requests library even the best route? Is there an easier way to run jQuery type stuff from Python?
 - Is json.dumps equivalent enough to JSON.stringify?
 - What is "$.cookie" and how do I do something similar in Python?
 - How do I do the "completion event" that the AJAX request does using requests in Python?

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks very much!